# Roofing : Pros and cons of re-roofing or re-layering

Tags: roof

I am considering changing my roof which is 28 years old. I was quoted a total new roof at $9K and a re-layering (putting second layer over the first one) at $6K.

Any comments on what is the downside for the re-layer option?

Comment: Most roofing manufacturers won’t provide warranty for overlaid roofs.

Comment: At least some regulatory bodies don't allow overlaying either.

Comment: Could you clarify what your current roof is made of.  The difference between slate and thatch lifetimes is quite marked!

Comment: Normal flat shingles. My state and town allows second layer of normal shingles

Answer (score 11):

Do not relayer. Here are some of the reasons.

1. The added layer adds needless extra weight to the roof.
2. Second and third layer shingles do not last as long as a new base layer.
3. The added layer will never lay as flat as a base layer and creates more chances for pockets to form where water can backup under the shingles.
4. Full rip off and replacement allows for inspection of roof boards / sheathing and replacement if necessary.
5. Full replacement allows for much better re-do of the flashing. Relayering generally makes a total mess of the flashing trying to add new on top of old and inviting new leaks.

Comment: ^^ this, especially because it's been almost 30 years since your roof deck has seen the light of day...

Comment: And all of this for only a modest increase in price over relayering. It's your *roof* --- don't go cheap on it.